# Not found solution for solve right overflowed right on my app

Tags: flutter, input

[image]

I come to you with this overflow problem

i try many solution proposed on stackoverflow but not solved as singlescrollview, padding...

i get this when i try to copy on all my app textformfield

this is my body with listview and padding for fix scroll and bottom overflowed

```
 body:

    ScrollConfiguration(
      child: new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),


      child: ListView(


        children: <Widget>[
          new Form(


            key: formKey,


            child: new Column(

              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: createInputs() + createButton(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    behavior: MyBehavior(),

    ),
```

And email textformfield input in a widget

```
         SizedBox(height: 10.0,),

      new TextFormField(
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          //     labelText: 'Email',
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey,
          border: OutlineInputBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
          //   enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.pink), ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder( borderSide: BorderSide(color : Colors.transparent),),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: myFocusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.grey : Colors.white),



        ),
        validator: (value){
          return value.isEmpty ? 'Email is required' : null;
        },
        onSaved: (value)
        {
          return _email = value;
        },
      ),

      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been reported [#35826](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35826) and it's being worked on link: 
 [#39624](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/39624) for as temp solution you could just edit: **flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_selection.dart** delete line **48** and select all button will not be displayed.

```
  if (handleSelectAll != null) FlatButton(child: 
  Text(localizations.selectAllButtonLabel), onPressed: handleSelectAll),
```

Remember to rebuild as hot reload will not work for this change.

Comment: It not the best solution but it working fine . Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have run into an actual Flutter bug, and this has nothing to do with your code:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35826

The [current workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35826#issuecomment-538008409) is to change the minimum width of buttons in your button theme:

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(minWidth: 10,),
        textTheme: TextTheme(button: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
)
```

That change allows the buttons to be closer together and prevent the overflow.

There is an [open PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/39624) to fix this issue properly, but has not yet been merged.